# Script PHP de longa duração não concluindo até o final

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);

ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* CONECTION */
$conn = mysqli_connect('foo','foo','foo','foo') or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES UTF8;') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

/* GENERATE SLUG */
function _slug($string) {
    return strtolower(preg_replace(['/[[:punct:]]+/', '/[[:space:]\s]+/'], ['', '-'], trim(stripslashes(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string)))));
}

$url = 'enderecodosistema:porta'; // url sem a barra final
$limit = 50000; // limite total
$i = 1;
$file = 1;
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select matricula, aluno, data_matricula from escola") or die( mysqli_error($conn) );
$total = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while($asc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $student = _slug($asc['aluno']);
    $enrollment = $asc['matricula'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($asc['data_matricula']));
    if($i == 1) {
        $sitemap = "sitemap_{$file}.xml";
        $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "urlset" ));
        $root->setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
        $root->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
        $root->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
        $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
    }   
    $child = $sxe->addChild('url');
    $child->addChild('loc', $url.'/'.$student.'/'.$enrollment);
    $child->addChild('lastmod', date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($date)));    
    if($i == $limit) {  
        $dom->save($sitemap);
        $i = 0;
        $file++;
    }    
    $i++;
}
if($limit >= $total) {
    $dom->save($sitemap);
    $i = 0;
}

if($file-1) {
    $sitemap = "sitemap.xml";
    $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "sitemapindex" ));
    $root->setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
    $root->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
    $root->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
    for($j = 1; $j <= $file-1; $j++) {
        $child = $sxe->addChild('sitemap');
        $child->addChild('loc', $url.'/sitemap_'.$j.'.xml');
    }
     $dom->save($sitemap);

}

?>
```

Ele cria um sitemap (com limite de 50 mil urls por arquivo) dos alunos, puxando de um banco de dados.

Acontece que o banco de dados está muito grande e o script demora muito tempo e não roda até o final.

É possível adaptar o código (com qualquer solução) para que ele seja "executado em partes", evitando que seja encerrado sem concluir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar paginação a cada requisição e dar um `refresh` no script a cada 1 segundo.

Veja um exemplo:

```
    $pg = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] + 1 : 1;
    $limit = ($pg - 1) * 10 .",10"; // limite de 10 alunos a cada requisição

    // query com limite de resultados
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select matricula, aluno, data_matricula from escola LIMIT $limit") or die( mysqli_error($conn) );
    $stop = $mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0; 
    // verifica se há mais registros -- se não houver a variável $stop irá terminar o script

    while($asc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        # [...] faça tudo aqui [...]
    }

    if(!$stop) // se não for para PARAR... de um refresh na página após 1 segundo
    header("Refresh: 1; url = meuScript.php?pagina=$pg"); // altere a URL para aonde está este script
```

Se você quiser um limite de 50 por exemplo:

```
$limit = ($pg - 1) * 50 .",50";
```

Seu script ficaria assim:

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(1);

    ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /* CONECTION */
    $conn = mysqli_connect('foo','foo','foo','foo') or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES UTF8;') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    /* GENERATE SLUG */
    function _slug($string) {
        return strtolower(preg_replace(['/[[:punct:]]+/', '/[[:space:]\s]+/'], ['', '-'], trim(stripslashes(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string)))));
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # PAGINAÇÃO
    $pg = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] + 1 : 1;
    $limite = ($pg - 1) * 10 .",10"; // limite de 10 alunos a cada requisição
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $url = 'enderecodosistema:porta'; // url sem a barra final
    $limit = 50000; // limite total
    $i = 1;
    $file = $pg;

    // INSERIDO O LIMIT NA QUERY
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select matricula, aluno, data_matricula from escola LIMIT $limite") or die( mysqli_error($conn) );
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($total == 0) // SE NÃO HOUVER MAIS REGISTROS PARE A APLICAÇÃO
    exit;

    while($asc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $student = _slug($asc['aluno']);
        $enrollment = $asc['matricula'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($asc['data_matricula']));
        if($i == 1) {
            $sitemap = "sitemap_{$file}.xml";
            $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "urlset" ));
            $root->setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
            $root->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
            $root->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
            $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
        }   
        $child = $sxe->addChild('url');
        $child->addChild('loc', $url.'/'.$student.'/'.$enrollment);
        $child->addChild('lastmod', date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($date)));    
        if($i == $limit) {  
            $dom->save($sitemap);
            $i = 0;
            $file++;
        }    
        $i++;
    }
    if($limit >= $total) {
        $dom->save($sitemap);
        $i = 0;
    }

    if($file-1) {
        $sitemap = "sitemap.xml";
        $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "sitemapindex" ));
        $root->setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
        $root->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
        $root->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
        $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
        for($j = 1; $j <= $file-1; $j++) {
            $child = $sxe->addChild('sitemap');
            $child->addChild('loc', $url.'/sitemap_'.$j.'.xml');
        }
         $dom->save($sitemap);

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # R F R E S H
    header("Refresh: 1; url = meuScript.php?pagina=$pg"); 
    //                            ^ AQUI
    // ALTERE A URL = {O SEU SCRIPT} ?pagina=$pg
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: desculpe a minha ignorância, mas como ficaria no meu código? Não consegui adicionar.

Comment: @Marcelo mais tarde eu farei a alteração.

Comment: @Marcelo fiz a edição

Comment: não funcionou. O script roda mas não cria os arquivos.
Esse limit na query, qual o motivo? O $limit 50k acima, é o limite de urls para cada arquivo (acredito que esse seja o erro, não?) De qualquer forma não funcionou. Fiz todas as alterações, inclusive, a no final do script

Comment: @Marcelo o limit é o limite no banco de dados... Ele vai puxar de 50 em 50 registros.

Comment: @Marcelo como você puxa as matriculas da tabela banco... cada segundo vai puxar 50 matriculas

Comment: entendi! Refiz novamente e nada. Não apresenta erros, carrega muito rápido (o que é estranho) mas não cria os arquivos .

Comment: @Marcelo acabei de editar o codigo... tinha um erro aqui `if($total == 0)`

Comment: @Marcelo estava assim : `if(!$total == 0)`

Comment: Entendi! Agora ele está contando as páginas, mas ele só cria 1 sitemap (com 10 resultados) e o sitemap.xml (indice) final. No browser, a paginação continua mudando, mas sem a criação dos arquivos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90878/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-marcelo).

Comment: Alguém que me deu -1 poderia, por favor, explicar o motivo?

Comment: Apenas para constar, o código funcionou perfeito! Obrigado Andrei!